# Python class/method comment and intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have seen that the comments I write at the top of my Python methods and and classes is the same text that pops up when I am using them in my code. I have also seen that some formatting hints can be made in the comments, and that will translate into pretty rendering in the popup text (for instance, putting a bunch of "-"'s under a heading makes the font bigger and bolder). What other formatting is there and what are the hints? Specifically, is there "code" formatting that renders in monospace? I like to put code samples in my comments sometimes and that would look great.

Finally, does this all have a name? I tried googling what I was trying to do and it was hard because I didn't know what it was called.

Comment: most likely they are Markdown text/comments

Comment: I don't think so, because surrounding a word with douple asterisks doesn't make it render as bold in the popup text. It just shows the asterisks. I think it is some sort of subset of markdown, but I can't find where it is documented.